# how to animate camera zooming and FOV keyframes

Tags: animation, camera

you know how you can, like, stretch the camera out to change the FOV? how do I make a keyframe of this movement, to sort of zoom in and out?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the properties for the camera is a value for Focal Length [image]

If you hover over the value and hit 'I' on your keyboard, you will create a keyframe for that value - at that frame.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively if you don't want to remember the shortcut, you can click on the little dot on the right of the field to record a keyframe

Comment: thanks! that helps!